# Split a JavaScript variable into 2 where an X separate 2 numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript variable which holds a `width X height` value like this `12x24`

I need to take `var size = '12x24';`

and create a separate width and height variable like so:

```
var width = 12;
var height = 24;
```

any help please.  The number of digits right or left of the X can be any amount but the X is the constant separator.

Comment: Sounds like a simple split.  What seems to be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var size = '12x24';
var widthAndHeight = size.split('x');
var width = parseInt(widthAndHeight[0]);
var height = parseInt(widthAndHeight[1]);
```

`size.split('x')` returns an array containing `12` and `24`; just set `width` to the first element and `height` to the second.

Since `split()` returns an array of strings, we need to convert the width and height to integers using `parseInt()` which converts a string to an integer. (You might not need to do this depending on what you intend to do with the width and height variables)

Comment: You are not doing the same as `var width = 12` as requested, instead it is like `var width = '12'`. Isn't it? Pretty different, it results in a string instead of a number.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()`

```js
var size = '12x24';
var splat = size.split('x');

var width = splat[0];
var height = splat[1]

console.log(width);
console.log(height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like this

```
var size = '12x24';
var sizeArr = size.split("x");

var width = sizeArr[0];
var height = sizeArr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var size = '12x24';
var wh = size.split('x');
var width = wh[0];
var height = wh[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to extract numbers (not strings), so I suggest what follows:

```
var arr = size.split('x');
var w = arr[0] && +arr[0] || 0;
var h = arr[1] && +arr[1] || 0;
```

The solution above has a few extra check and uses `0` as a default value if the string is malformed.
You can easily change this behavior according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`split` and `Regexp` are slow, in contrast to `indexOf` (given that the string length won't vary):

```html
<script src="http://broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/JSLitmus.js"></script>
<script>
JSLitmus.test('Regexp', function() {
    '12x24'.match(/(.+)x(.+)/);
});
JSLitmus.test('String split', function() {
    '12x24'.split('x');
});
JSLitmus.test('String indexOf', function() {
    var a = '12x24'.slice(0, 2),
        b = '12x24'.slice(3, 5);
});
</script>
```